# Packet loss Test

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, network-programming, packet-loss

Does any one have a idea about how to do a packet loss test like in
[ping test](http://www.pingtest.net/) from flash technologies (Flash or Flex)?
Please help me.

Comment: Hey folks any idea about this? Please save me.

Comment: pingtest.net seems to be using a java plugin in order to test packet loss. Also -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907783/i-need-to-ping-to-an-network-with-flash-or-actionscript

Comment: @bug-a-lot Thanks for your response. Pingtest.net using java applet named LQApplet.jar. I downloaded it and inspect using NetBeans. But I did not find out, a way to do mentioned task. Any way, I am going to do this on http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no, you cannot do an actual ping from Flash since it lacks the ability to send ICMP packets.  However, I have to ask, what is your reasoning for it's usage?

The only way to do it (which isn't really a ping) would be to try to load something extremely small from the server, or have a way for the server to do a callback using a service of sorts.  All of this would of course be through HTTP.

Comment: Thanks,I need to calculate 1. Download speed 2. Upload speed 3. Latency (Round Trip Time) 4. Jitter 5. Packet loss 6. Network availability ,
of the client machine. How can I do it?

Comment: Why?  There's already tools out there that does this.  Download and upload speed isn't hard.  Make it download a file that's a few megs, time the seconds it take to do it; the calculation is very easy. The latency is as simple as calling a web service that returns a boolean or something and time it to see how long it takes.  I don't think it's possible to do Jitter and packet loss in a reliable way.  Network availability doesn't make sense because the client computer needed to be on the internet to download the swf file.  I would suggest you do more research. But again, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes. Download, upload and latency OK. :) . Problem was to calculate jitter and packet loss. It get worse when I got to know that flash technology can not send ICMP packets. That is why, I wanted to know how the pingtst.net guys did it. And thanks again for your kindness.

Comment: pingtest.net guys *did not* do anything using Flash other than show the data that was created using a Java applet, which can do everything you just asked.

Comment: Do you have any idea about, how this done in java? Because I am kind of new to Java and it will great help if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: I know java, but I've never done any ping related stuff with it.  I would recommend you do some research, I'm sure there's a library out there that already does most of this stuff for you.  The communication from Java applet to Flash is probably through Javascript.  If you can't find your answer for the Java part, I would recommend you create a new question in the Java section.  Please accept my answer.