# I need to ping a website with ActionScript or Animate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I had found this code ( [I need to ping to an network with flash or actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907783/i-need-to-ping-to-an-network-with-flash-or-actionscript) )
Im not sure i understand it or how to use it exactly - I need for this to redirect to another frame if it worked and another if it failed

Is anyone able to help?

```
    var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, ldrStatus);

var url:String = "URL-TO-SITE";
var limit:int = 10;

var time_start:Number;
var time_stop:Number;
var times:int;

ping();

function ping():void
{
    trace("pinging", url);

    times = 0;
    doThePing();
}

function doThePing():void
{
    time_start = getTimer();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

function ldrStatus(evt:*):void
{
    if(evt.status == 200)
    {
        time_stop = getTimer();
        trace("got response in", time_stop - time_start, "ms");
    }

    times++;
    if(times < limit) doThePing();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to ping to an network with flash or actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907783/i-need-to-ping-to-an-network-with-flash-or-actionscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is trying to load a website 10 times and check the response. I would get rid of the limit though, it make no sense to try it 10 times in a row.

Don't forget that you will need a crossdomain.xml file on your server to be able to access it from flash.

You will need to add some more things for your purpose:

```
// add an event listener for a failed call
ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ldrFailed);
ldr.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR , ldrSecurityError);

function ldrFailed(evt:*):void
{   
    // loader failed (no internet connection), try to ping again
    doFailedRedirect();
}

function ldrSecurityError(evt:*):void
{   
    // There is an internet connection but probably something is wrong with your crossdomain.xml
    doFailedRedirect();
}

function doRedirect():void
{   
    // make your redirect here
}

function doFailedRedirect():void
{   
    // something went wrong, do your failed redirect here
}
```

Adjust the ldrStatus function:

```
function ldrStatus(evt:*):void
{
    if(evt.status == 200)
    {
        // server responded with status 200 wich means everything is fine 
        time_stop = getTimer();
        trace("got response in", time_stop - time_start, "ms");
        doRedirect();
    }
    else
    {
        // there is an internet connection but the server returns something else (probably something is wrong with the server)
        doFailedRedirect();
    }
}
```